# Удаление строки не входящей в дерево

Tags: php, cms, mysql

**Готово!**

Все элементарно просто!

- Один запрос.
- Одна рекурсивная функция.

Например, url такой `/test/sm/todo`.

Циклом проходим по всем страницам и строим дерево всех потомков, записываем в массив, далее функцией `max()` выводим самый длинный массив, он и будет верным и нужным деревом.

---

**Есть таблица страниц** - элементарное дерево parentID.

[image]

Например, мне нужно вытащить страницы по таким href - /cm/todo. В структуре страниц у меня есть две todo страницы, но они расположены на разных уровнях вложенности.

Мне нужно вытащить только те которые расположены в дереве, то есть нужно вытащить только

- / - главная страница
- cm - 1 уровень
- todo - 2 уровень

**Но когда я пишу вот такой запрос**

```
select id, pid, alias 
from `pages` 
where `alias` in ("/","cm","todo") 
order by `id`
```

**Результат**

[image]

У меня выводится лишняя страница todo, та которая расположена на втором уровне наравне с `cm`.

Тот, кто вник в ситуацию, понял что вторая строка лишняя, т.к. она не входит в дерево. В дерево входит 1,3,4 строка.

**Вопрос:** какой нужен запрос чтобы убрать вот этот косяк?

- можно использовать PHP для обработки результата.

**Предпринятые действия:** применял реверсию для результата запроса, далее через рекурсивную функцию выводил верное дерево. НО: есть такой запрос

```
select id, pid, alias 
from `pages` 
where `alias` in ("/","todo") 
order by `id`
```

который выводит на чистую воду, и говорит о том, что неправильно делать так, как я сделал.

**Структура таблицы `pages`:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(200) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `pid` (`pid`,`alias`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=74 ;

-- Дамп данных

INSERT INTO `pages` (`id`, `pid`, `alias`) VALUES (1, 0, '/'),(44, 43, 'login'),
(43, 1, 'admin'),(46, 1, '404'),(52, 1, 'todo'),(54, 1, 'news'),(55, 1, 'pdd'),(58, 1, 'services'),(68, 67, 'todolist'),(67, 1, 'maxim'),(66, 64, '123'),(70, 69, 'smartprogress'),(69, 1, 'test'),(71, 70, 'listtodo'),(72, 1, 'cm'),(73, 72, 'todo');
```

Comment: Я чуть не вник, pid не должен повторятся?

Comment: select id, pid, alias 
    from `pages` 
    where `alias` in ("/","cm","todo") 
    order by `id`

Следует понимать как: Выбрать поля id, pid, alias из таблицы pages при условии, что alias входит в список допустимых значений ("/", "cm", "todo"), упорядочить по id.

Что запросили - то и получили

Comment: Node_pro, да, но всё строки должны быть взаимосвязаны между собой через id и pid соответственно.

Comment: у второй строки pid=1, и она входит в дерево!

Comment: nolka, да-да, всё правильно, но мне нужно найти всю ветку от / до последнего todo, а вторая строка todo является лишней

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле тут можно использовать рекурсию для получения этих "хлебных крошек" иначе, да, как показывает практика нужно юзать запросы вида как описал [[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov), но они слишком большие для такой задачи.

В моем первом движке была именно такая структура таблиц.
Но мне выборка твоя непонятна, ты что её делаешь?

Если тебе нужно сделать так

> нужно вытащить страницы по таким href
> - /cm/todo

```
select id,alias 
from `pages` 
where `alias` ="cm" 
order by `id`
```

Тогда ты идешь по такому пути. Ищи сначала корень своего URL это cm потом находи его вместе с его ID в БД, ну а следующим простым запросом ты сможешь вытащить его потомков

```
select id, pid, alias 
from `pages` 
where pid=$result['id']; // $result из предыдущего sql запроса
order by `id`
```

И получишь список всех потомков. У меня было так, пусть это 2 запроса, но они маленькие и выполняются быстро нежели 2 join'a.

Так что смотри сам.

**//upd**

> Нет, я получу одну страницу которая
> находится на уровень ниже, а не всех
> потомков.

Ты получишь всех потомков с нужным ID, да на один следующий уровень! А чтобы получить всех потомков вообще и всех уровней и допустим вывести их в тегах <ul></ul> тогда можно написать рекурсию.

ps ну немного включайте мозг ребят, если логики нет, то вопросы задавать какой смысл, написано 2 ответа.

**Я на 100% уверен, что ни один запрос ты даже не попробовал чтобы говорить о том что ты получишь а что нет.**

pps

```
select id, pid, alias 
from `pages` 
where `alias` in ("/","cm","todo") 
order by `id`
```

Этот запрос можно выкинуть, он никогда не будет работать как нужно т.к. нужен join в него либо разбить его на 2 запроса как я уже описал!

Comment: > И получишь список всех потомков.

Нет, я получу одну страницу которая находится на уровень ниже, а не всех потомков.


Мне нужно вытаскивать все страницы, потому как я потом прохожу циклом, обрабатываю их, и проверяю на предмет обработки страницы модулем


То есть, по такому запросу

    select id, pid, alias 
    from `pages` 
    where `alias` in ("/","cm","todo") 
    order by `id`

мне нужно вытащить именно нужные страницы в указанном порядке, никак не иначе. Понятно, что таким запросом это не сделаешь.

Comment: Это будет рекурсия, и её тут не избежать при такой структуре данных никак!

Вот @Yura Ivanov опередил меня.
тут при таком раскладе нужно менять структуру и использовать Nested Sets

Comment: Сделал. В начале поста некоторая инфа.

Comment: @exec не самый лучший вариант вы выбрали. запросы в цикле - плохо на производительности скажется, дергать базу надо по минимуму. кроме того количество обрабатываемых данных довольно большое, лишние действия с лишними массивами. подумайте про формирование запроса как у меня в ответе в цикле по частям url.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, у меня один запрос. Остальное массивы и циклы.

Comment: @exec, т.е. вы одним запросом получаете все дерево целиком, а дальше в массивах ищите ваш путь? или все же запрос повторяете рекурсивно? оба варианта, на мой взгляд, не оптимальны.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я получаю только то, что нужно. А дальше обрабатываю, да.

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен, что удовлетворит результат, но можно так:

```
select p1.id as id1, p2.id as id2, p3.id as id3
from `pages` p1
join `pages` p2 on p1.id = p2.pid and p2.alias = "cm"
join `pages` p3 on p2.id = p3.pid and p3.alias = "todo"
where p1.alias = "/"
```

Результат:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3
1   72  73
```

Comment: слишком сложно, запросы всегда разные и длина их тоже разная

Comment: @exec, дело в том, что такое хранение деревьев не даст возможности в один запрос (без джойнов таблицы с самой собой) получить связь узлов. Либо должна быть избыточность хранения данных (перечень всех родителей для каждого узла) недостатки:

  - при переносе веток в дереве нужно перестраивать список предков для всей ветки
  - если дерево будет большое, запрос будет тормозить.

, либо придется конструировать запрос каждый раз по нужному пути:

  - Бьем строку по слэшам.
  - Циклом формируем необходимое количество джойнов.
  - Выполняем запрос.
  - Циклом по полям результата потом обходим крошки

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для этих целей NestedSets

Comment: Да.&nbsp;&nbsp;